# converting an address of a struct to string

Tags: c, struct, heap-memory, valgrind

I am trying to convert a struct address to a string, but I have tried two ways to write the code.
The first one has leaded to errors on valgrind, and the second one didn't. And its the only think I change when reusing valgrind but the results are different.
I would really appreciate it if you can tell what is the problem.

The first one:

```
typedef struct Unit_t *Unit;

//Creating a unit

char* unit_address = malloc(sizeof(unit) + 1);
int convert_result = sprintf(unit_address,"%p",(void*)unit);

//Checking the return result and freeing the allocated memory
```

The second one:

```
typedef struct Unit_t *Unit;

//Creating a unit

char unit_address[30];
int convert_result = sprintf(unit_address,"%p",(void*)unit);

//Checking the return result
```

I want to allocate the memory since I can't suppose what would be the length of the pointer (at least not in the HW I'm doing).

Comment: What is `unit` (not `Unit`)?

Comment: I have created a Unit_t struct, and the variable unit as a pointer to this struct.

Comment: Just allocate enough for the longest string + 1.

Comment: You are not taking into account the number of bytes that %p generates, it is not sizeof(unit) it would be number of bytes that %p generates on your system + 1. Just print it out instead using printf to see the length. Alternatively unit_address = malloc(30);

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(unit)` is the number of bytes of the binary representation of `unit`.
In some environment, it will be less than the number of bytes to be used in string representation.
For example, if pointers are 4-byte long and they are represented in 8-digit hex string, 
 `sizeof(unit)` (=4) is smaller than the length of representing string (=8) and out-of-bounds write will occur.

To allocate memory dynamically,

1. Allocate sufficient buffer
2. Convert the pointer to string there
3. Measure length of resulting string
4. Allocate memory sufficient for the string

Example implementation (error checking should be added and `snprintf()` should be used instead of `sprintf()` to make it safer):

```
char unit_address_buffer[512];
int convert_result = sprintf(unit_address_buffer,"%p",(void*)unit);
char* unit_address = malloc(strlen(unit_address_buffer) + 1);
strcpy(unit_address, unit_address_buffer);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can't suppose a maximal length of a pointer due to the course staff instructions. Is there perhaps another way without using a buffer ?

Comment: You can use return value of `snprintf()` to check if the buffer had sufficient length. The length is OK if the return value is non-negative and less then the buffer size specified. If the buffer length was not sufficient, inclease (say, double) buffer size and try again.